# How to apply camera feature without moving to use photo and retake in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera

I stuck to apply square focus in UIImage picker controller and how to stay on camera page without moving to another page same like below screen. please help me. I tried to implement in custom overlay for this but in square focus not coming.[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "stay on camera page without moving to another page" can you elaborate this.

Comment: When i press camera button it is moving to the Use Photo and retake.When i click camera i want to stay on same like above screen.

Comment: I want apply same like screenshot

Comment: which one you use for camera UIimagePickerController or other library?

Answer (score 0):

In my UIImagePickerController, the square is not displayed at first, but when I tap the screen, it shows at that time.

Comment: Without taping the screen is possible.

Comment: I made the custom overlay for this but in that i'm not able to put square.So now i want to apply same feature above screen shot. But when i press camera spinner it is moving to use photo.

Comment: can i know what device you are using, i think it is iphone 4 or 4s right?

Comment: I'm using 5c, Ipad

Answer (score 0):

[image: auto focus image]

download the above image(ask your designer to give you better image) and add to your project.

add this code while creating imagepicker

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(createAutoFocus)];
                [overlayView addGestureRecognizer:tap];//overlayview is your custom overlay
```

then add this method in your class

```
-(void)createAutoFocus{

    // NSLog(@"click");
 CGPoint touchPoint=[recognizer locationInView:overlayView];//overlayview is your custom overlay
    // NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    UIImageView *imgViewFocus = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 80, 80)];
    imgViewFocus.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"focus.png"];
    imgViewFocus.alpha = 0.8;
    [overlayView addSubview:imgViewFocus];
    [imagePickerCustom setCameraOverlayView:overlayView];//your customimagepicker
    [imgViewFocus performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];

}
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: we don't want on touch. we want automatically.